# How to become superuser without terminal

Tags: software-center

I have accidentally edited bash.bashrc and made it run a wrong command so I cannot enter any terminal window at all. How can I become superuser without sudo su in the terminal, so I can reedit and correct bash?

KdeSudo does't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Does the below help?

```
gksudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

You could always run a terminal and tell Bash to ignore that rc file:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash --norc'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, You can get to a system prompt by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> and when finished, return to the GUI interface with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions

- Enter from another tty (not from graphical one .eg tty1)
- use shortcuts ,if works
- restart and enter recovery mode, then select shell prompt
- Close computer, enter live cd and edit bashrc. then Restart and see what happens?